# Question not migrated properly

Tags: support, specific-question, migration

[This question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/16066/what-to-consider-a-click) has been  migrated to Stack Overflow.

At least there is a comment to say that a moderator was going to migrate and there is the "migrated" text at the bottom which has a link to the [question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844678/what-to-consider-a-click).

But:

1. The question title doesn't have [migrated] in it.
2. The answer hasn't been deleted.
3. The question isn't locked - I can still add comments (if I wanted to).

So what went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug, I reopened it :)

Comment: Ah - you need to clear the migration history and then contact the Stack Overflow mods so they can delete their copy. Though it has an answer so it really should be re-migrated and merged/